# How could i target a div and it's child to handle a click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `<div class="stock"></div>`wrapped around :

```
<div class="stockAdd"></div>
<div class="stockRemove"></div>
<div class="stockInput"></div>
```

I want to prevent a click inside my .stock to trigger a function. For now i have the following :

```
    if ($(event.target).is('.stockInput') || $(event.target).is('.stockAdd') || $(event.target).is('.stockRemove')) {
        console.log("Ajout stock");
        return
    }
```

Isn't there a better way to select thos three divs ? The `$(event.target).is('.stock')` don't get the job done when i click my nested divs.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to catch click events on `.stockAdd`, `.stockRemove`, and `.stockInput`, but not on other elements within `.stock` itself, is that correct?

If so, a delegated event can take care of that without any need to manually check the event target:

```js
$('.stock').on('click', '.stockAdd, .stockRemove, .stockInput', function() {
  alert("Clicked");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="stock">
  <div class="stockAdd">stockAdd</div>
  <div class="stockRemove">stockRemove</div>
  <div class="stockInput">stockInput</div>
  <div>No event</div>
</div>
```

I would **strongly** recommend against depending on `event.target` here; it's too fragile. Any HTML tags nested inside your desired targets would break things:

```js
$('.stock').on('click', function(event) {
    if (event.target.className=="stockAll") {
    alert("clicked");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="stock">
  <div class="stockAll">
    This <b> will not work if someone clicks in the bold area</b> but works outside
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a separate class to all of them like `.stock-inner` and then grab them all with `$('.stock-inner')` or you can use a `$("div[class^='stock-inner'])` - this will grab the parent `.stock` div...

Also, to reject a click event within the handler you're gunna want to use `e.preventDefault()` where `e` is the event object.

Answer (score 0):

the reason it doesn't work well on nested divs is they pass the conditional `if` in your example, to make it stricter you could add div to selector:

```
if ($(event.target).is('div.stockInput') ||    $(event.target).is('div.stockAdd') || $(event.target).is('div.stockRemove'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can attach the event on `.stock` and then filter using the `event.target`.

HTML

```
<div class="stock" style="border: 10px solid #000;">
  <div class="stockAdd">Add</div>
  <div class="stockRemove">Remove</div>
  <div class="stockInput">Input</div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$('.stock').on('click', function(e) {

  if( e.target.className !== 'stock' ) {
    console.log(e.target.className);
  }

});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eqa8h11o/1/)